# How do I get values from for loop in a list?

Tags: python, list, append

I am trying to print the output of the for loop given below in a list but I get the following results:

```
import math
S= [(1,2),(3,4),(-1,1),(6,-7),(0, 6),(-5,-8),(-1,-1),(6,0),(1,-1)]
p,q = 3,-4
dist = []
for x,y in S:
    dist=[]
    cos_dist = math.acos((x*p + y*q)/((math.sqrt(x**2 + y**2))*(math.sqrt(p**2 + q**2))))
    dist.append(cos_dist)
    print(dist)
```

Here, the output is :

```
[2.0344439357957027]
[1.8545904360032246]
[2.9996955989856287]
[0.06512516333438509]
[2.498091544796509]
[1.2021004241368467]
[1.4288992721907328]
[0.9272952180016123]
[0.14189705460416438]
```

But I want it to be:

```
 [2.0344439357957027,1.8545904360032246,2.9996955989856287,0.06512516333438509,2.498091544796509,1.2021004241368467,1.4288992721907328,0.9272952180016123,0.14189705460416438]
```

I have tried using

```
print(','.join(dist))
```

but it says

```
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, float found
```

How do I get the output I want?

Comment: You are reassigning ```dist``` again inside the loop. Every time,the previous list gets discarded. So you only get 1 element. Remove ```dist=[]``` from the loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, move the `dist` initialization outside of the loop.

Then you must convert floating-point numbers to strings before joining them, either in the loop:

```
dist.append(str(cos_dist))
```

Or after the loop:

```
print(','.join(map(str, dist)) )
```

Overall, list comprehension is a better tool for list construction:

```
dist = [math.acos((x*p + y*q) / ((math.sqrt(x**2 + y**2))\
                      *(math.sqrt(p**2 + q**2)))) for x,y in S]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you see closely:

```
for x,y in S:
    dist=[]
```

You are assigning `dist=[]` every time. So, with every iteration, the previous values are discarded and a new blank list called `dist` is created. That is why, you only get 1 element.

Instead, remove the line where you define the list. Also, move `print(dist)` outside

```
import math
S= [(1,2),(3,4),(-1,1),(6,-7),(0, 6),(-5,-8),(-1,-1),(6,0),(1,-1)]
p,q = 3,-4
dist = []
for x,y in S:
    
    cos_dist = math.acos((x*p + y*q)/((math.sqrt(x**2 + y**2))*(math.sqrt(p**2 + q**2))))
    dist.append(cos_dist)
print(dist)
```

An alternative:

```
dist=[math.acos((x*p + y*q)/((math.sqrt(x**2 + y**2))*(math.sqrt(p**2 + q**2)))) for x,y in S]
```

Comment: Above code was very helpful and it printed the numbers in a list. The list comprehension with 'cos_dist =' part shows invalid syntax error because '=' symbol maybe so it's better to not use 'cos_dist' variable I guess.

Comment: Also, is there a way I can show which value of 'dist' corresponds to the respective points in 'S'?

Comment: @AzizAhmed, I didn't get you?

Comment: the values in 'dist' are cosine distances for the coordinates in S. Now that I've printed the distances like '[2.0344439357957027,1.8545904360032246....]' can I print which points they belong to like '(1,2),(3,4)..'?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import math
S= [(1,2),(3,4),(-1,1),(6,-7),(0, 6),(-5,-8),(-1,-1),(6,0),(1,-1)]
p,q = 3,-4
dist = []
for x,y in S:
    cos_dist = math.acos((x*p + y*q)/((math.sqrt(x**2 + y**2))*(math.sqrt(p**2 + q**2))))
    dist.append(cos_dist)
print(dist)
```

Point 1, your list declaration should be outside the for loop otherwise you are going to have only the latest element in the list. Point 2, You should print outside of the loop to print all the element as you showed in your expected output. This will do the thing, no need of *','.join()*.

In case you want to use the join then use

```
print('[' + ','.join(map(str, dist)) + ']')
```

Which will give the same result.